# How hot can heat pump boilers feasibly go?

Tags: heat-transfer

Over on Worldbuilding, [someone sorely wanted a battery-electric *steam locomotive*.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/245480/is-there-any-reason-a-society-might-use-steam-electric-motors-in-their-trains-ra)  Doing that with resistive heating is a non-starter because of the heinously poor efficiency of the traditional single-expansion puff-and-chuff transmission.

But then I thought, "Wait. Heat pumps are dramatically over-unity, and they run great on electric. Can they compensate for that?" Further thinking, "Most of the heat we need can be found exiting the pistons and going up into the smokebox, which is right next to the boiler! And it's already quite hot, *that being the problem with steam locomotive efficiency*, so we don't need an exceedingly wide range heat pump here."

Presumably this would be multiple stages of heat pump, and exhaust steam would interchange through one evaporator stage after another on its way out the stack.

Each stage would have an evaporator in the steam exhaust path, so the highest stage got the hottest steam of course.

The second stage would exclusively serve a refrigerant-refrigerant heat exchanger to provide supplemental heat for the highest stage.

The third stage would exclusively serve, again, a refrigerant-refrigerant heat exchange to support the 2nd stage, repeating.

The lowest stage would have evaporators interchanging to air (not steam) and would be the primary source of heat for cold startup, if feasible.

Assumptions:

Traditional side-rod steam locomotive with 2 pistons (3 adds great maintenance expense); single-expansion only (Mallets too slow). Space for mechanical equipment and heat exchangers is not a problem. Greenhouse gas impact of refrigerants not a factor as the industrial setting permits alternatives.

Boiler operating pressure is 2000 kPA above ambient (290 PSI).  Boiler temp is 485K (212C; 412F).  The general assumption is it would use "toaster" resistive heating for initial startup, possibly on shore power, and then rely on its own waste steam for heat once underway.

So...

The nut of my question is, is it feasible to "stack" multiple stages of heat pump to get to "steam boiler" temperature (210C/410F) and have any chance of being more efficient than a simple "toaster" resistive heating element?  Noting that it doesn't have to raise heat from -20C air, it'll be able to scavenge its own exhaust.